# How to handle User Authentication/Authorization on Pivotal Web Services/Cloud foundry Spring Cloud application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, pivotal-web-services

I am building an application which I'm intending to deploy on Pivotal Web Services. I want to secure the application using Spring Security. The Security should be role-based, and users should be able to register themselves in my application.

I want the application to work in a stateless way, I know how to handle a "user system" like this when it comes to stateful systems, using sessions, but I am completely clueless to handle this on PWS where you have multiple instances of the same application.

What's the best way to handle this? Do I have to set up an OAUTH2 server for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use sessions on cloudfoundry. The router actually knows how to handle stickiness using jsessionId. The [java buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md) also supports session replication and it's very simple to setup.

The fact that you have multiple instances should not be a problem as long as you use session replication. Take a look at [Spring Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) as well,  it should help you understand how to manage user state.

As per authentication, you don't need to use oAuth2. You can just use BASIC or any sort of authentication supported by [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)

If you want to leverage Spring Cloud, take a look at [Spring Cloud Security](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/) It's very simple to start a resource server and then using @EnableSSO on your applications. I'd recommend a good reading of Spring Security before diving into Spring Cloud Security.

Dr. Syer wrote a phenomenal [blog](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) entry on how to secure microservices using the api gateway pattern. <--- READ THIS

It's a lot to take, but it's the kind of question that is not easily answered without requiring some research first.